# Sending packets greater than 65,535 bytes in an SSH transport connection

Tags: ssh

Is there any way how to test (verify/demonstrate) that packets greater than 65,535 bytes in an SSH transport connection are dropped?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to re-build an existing open-source client or server and modify it to set a larger size.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254.html for details.  The maximum packet size is 4,294,967,296  (size is a uint32).

The other answer on this page is wrong - SSH builds its own packets over TCP/IP - the size that lower transport levels cut things up into is irrelevant for the question you're asking, which is about SSH packet sizes, not TCP packet sizes.

6.1 of the RFC 4253 has the wrong heading - it is *minimum* packet length, not maximum.  It doesn't mention a maximum, other than saying you SHOULD support larger than 35000.  Note that you're not allowed to go bigger than the other side says it accepts - hence why I said you need to re-build the "other end" from source specifically picking a bigger size, otherwise anything you test won't be allowed to send that big size.

Actually - since you said "dropped" - you might need to "hack" the thing you build so that it is capable of sending a packet larger than it knows the other side has already said it accepts - otherwise you won't be able to test that the other side properly drops anything, since it wouldn't have been sent.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there any way how to test that packets greater than 65535 bytes are dropped?

No.

SSH runs on top of TCP/IP so it is subject to the limitations of the underlying protocol.

You can't create a packet larger than 65535 bytes as that is the maximum size allowed by the Internet Protocol RFC.

If you can't create such a packet then you can't send one to test if it is dropped.

The Internet Header Format contains a Total Length field which is is 16 bits (which can have a maximum value of 65535 if all bits are set to one).

> 3.1.  Internet Header Format

> A summary of the contents of the internet header follows:
>
> ```
>     0                   1                   2                   3
>     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>    |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>    |         Identification        |Flags|      Fragment Offset    |
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>    |  Time to Live |    Protocol   |         Header Checksum       |
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>    |                       Source Address                          |
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>    |                    Destination Address                        |
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>    |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
>    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```
>
> Total Length: 16 bits
>
> Total Length is the length of the datagram, measured in octets,
> including internet header and data.  This field allows the length of a
> datagram to be up to 65,535 octets.  Such long datagrams are
> impractical for most hosts and networks.  All hosts must be prepared
> to accept datagrams of up to 576 octets (whether they arrive whole or
> in fragments).  It is recommended that hosts only send datagrams
> larger than 576 octets if they have assurance that the destination is
> prepared to accept the larger datagrams.
>
> The number 576 is selected to allow a reasonable sized data block to
> be transmitted in addition to the required header information.  For
> example, this size allows a data block of 512 octets plus 64 header
> octets to fit in a datagram.  The maximal internet header is 60
> octets, and a typical internet header is 20 octets, allowing a margin
> for headers of higher level protocols.

Source [RFC 791: Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)

---

#### Further Reading

- [maximum packet size for a TCP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613734/maximum-packet-size-for-a-tcp-connection)

Comment: If I'm parsing the standards right, this changed very slightly in IPv6. It still uses a 16-bit length field (and therefore a maximum of 65,535 octets), but that's the max payload length, not the max packet length (i.e. it doesn't include the IP header, although it does include any extension headers). Since the IPv6 header is 320 octets long, that gives a maximum total packet size of 65,855 octets. See [RFC 2460](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2460.txt), section 3.

Comment: Thank you answering the question. I am trying to test the SSH implementation and part of that is to verify the Maximum Packet Length as defined in 6.1 of the RFC 4253.
Does anyone know how to simulate/test sending an SSH packet 32768 bytes or more,  and a total packet    size of 35000 bytes or more?

Comment: @2116_daz You can use scapy or similar to a packet of 32768. Create a SSH packet of this length (4 bytes of packet_length, 1 byte padding length, n bytes payload, m bytes mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Golang SFTP client to customize max packet size and try to upload some amount of bytes. You can found more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726482/pkg-sftp-much-slower-than-linux-scp-why